# How add symbol in CSS for element?

Tags: html, css

I need to show symbol `&#9660;` in element div. How I can do at CSS?

For example, `<div>&#9660;</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or use `\25BC`

```css
div:after {
  content: '\25BC';
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the actual symbol:

▼

In the HTML itself.

Or if using CSS use the content: "▼"; property perhaps

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, you can only add content `:before` or `:after` an element:

```css
div:after {
  content:'▼';
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If you need the "▼" inside the `<div>`, then use JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('holder').innerHTML = '▼';
```

```html
<div id="holder"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use the actual symbol "▼".